# Remap keys like vi

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, 10.04, keyboard

I'd like to achieve a remapping of keys in a way that simulates the vi flow of having editing mode and command mode.
In Windows, it can be [achieved](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/home-row-computing) as explained in the site. In the comments, it is suggested a way that might work in Linux, but I can't put it to work.
To better explain what I want, this is an example of the effects with the Windows solution:
I'm editing something in notepad. If I press <kbd>f</kbd>, it should type an "f" letter. However if I press <kbd>CAPS</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, then it should move a line down (<kbd>CAPS</kbd> was configured as the command key).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap

Comment: @user606723: I know you can remap keys, but that's not what I'm asking. I've edited the question trying to put it clearer.

Comment: I am pretty sure you everything that you want with xmodmap.... Wait you want to have two different modes? hmm

Comment: @user606723: So I don't have to reach for the arrow keys while typing. Exactly the same as the vi key binding works. If can be done with xmodmap, can you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the link you provided, Paul explain how did he made it.
A slight modified way to do this would be like this:

**1)** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-keyboard-properties`.
Then go to Layouts > Options > Caps Lock key Behavior > "Make Caps Lock an additional Super"

**2)** Install [compizconfig settings manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) and [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool).

**3)** Open ccsm (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm).
Then go to Commands and set these commands and these shortcuts:

---

Command 1
sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "Left"

Shortcut 1
Super+h

---

Command 2
sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "Down"

Shortcut 2
Super+j

---

Command 3
sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "Up"

Shortcut 3
Super+k

---

Command 4
sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "Right"

Shortcut 4
Super+l

---

Hope you enjoy ;-)